# Want to show and hide data using jquery or javascript inside html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `span`s:

```
<span>Show link -3456
  <span>Hide link -n 1234 - 4567 -7777 -3456
  </span>
</span>
```

Basically first `span`'s link shows full number on click of show link and hides itself.

On click of hide I want to again regain the original state with show link and last 4 digits of number..

Could anyone please help me out I am stuck in such a simple code :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would start by linking to jQuery, then you would give the span that you want to hide an id. It would happen like so:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('#idofthespan').hide();
  
});
```

And if you want to respond to a click:

```js
$(function(){

$("#target").click(function() {
  
  $("#idofthespan").show();
  
});
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It was pretty simple. But I have one more query. Actually, I am having various such fields inside my table and for each field I need to show same hide/show functionality. Also the rows are being generated dynamically, so I use some kind of function that will work out for every field in same way..?

Answer (score 2):

You just simple need this have your html as

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
<span class="show">Show link -3456</span>
<span class="hide" style="display:none">Hide link -n 1234 - 4567 -7777 -3456</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>
<span class="show">Show link -3000</span>
<span class="hide" style="display:none">Hide link -n 1234 - 4567 -7777 -3456</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then using Jquery

```
$("span.show").on("click",function(){

     $(this).hide();
     $("span.hide").show();

})

$("span.hide").on("click",function(){

     $(this).hide();
     $("span.show").show();

})
```

**Updated**
For dynamically created multiples spans

```
   $("table").on("click","span.show",function(){

     $(this).hide();
     $(this).siblings("span.hide").show();

})

$("table").on("click","span.hide",function(){

     $(this).hide();
     $(this).siblings("span.show").show();

})
```

**Updated**
here is the fiddle working demo http://jsfiddle.net/cs6t3g48/2/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It was pretty simple. But I have one more query. Actually, I am having various such fields inside my table and for each field I need to show same hide/show functionality. Also the rows are being generated dynamically, so I use some kind of function that will work out for every field in same way..? eg : <tr><span id="show"></span><id="hide"span></span></tr> <tr><span id="show"></span><id="hide"span></span></tr>

Comment: Thank you very much brother. It is working as I wanted it to be. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <span id="shortInfo">
    <a href="#" onclick="ShowInfo(true)">Show link</a> -3456
 </span>
 <span id="longInfo" style="display:none">
    <a href="#" onclick="ShowInfo(false)">Hide link</a>  -n 1234 - 4567 -7777 -3456
 </span>
```

Without JQuery:

```
 var ShowInfo = function (showLong) {
           if (showLong) {
               document.getElementById("shortInfo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("longInfo").style.display = "block";
           }
           else
           {
               document.getElementById("shortInfo").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("longInfo").style.display = "none";
           }
       }
```

With JQuery:

```
 var ShowInfo = function (showLong) {
               if (showLong) {
                   $("#shortInfo").hide();
                   $("#longInfo").show();
               }
               else
               {
                   $("#shortInfo").show();
                   $("#longInfo").hide();
               }
           }
```